# I need to send a variable to another page using a for each table with php

Tags: php, html

My code is this:

```
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($stores as $store){
                echo '<tr> <td><a href="store_information.php?store_name=store[0]">'.$store[0].'</a></td> </tr>'; 
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Table and the links works perffectly, shows all the stores in a table and you can press anyone and you will be redirect to `store_information`,  but when I press the links I need to work with `$store_name` in the other page to show some specific data. I think that my problem is with the line `echo '<tr> <td><a href="store_information.php?store_name=store[0]">'.$store[0].'</a></td> </tr>';`. I need that every link send a different information. If I code the next in `$store_information`:

```
    <?php
echo $_GET['store_name'];
 ?>
```

Prints me in the page:

```
   $store
```

I need to print the name of the store which I select the link. For example: petstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to concatenate the actual PHP variable into the URL you're generating. Instead you're passing some literal text.

Replace

```
?store_name=store[0]">
```

with

```
?store_name='.$store[0].'">
```

and it should work better.